# Use HTML from local external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I basically want to embed an HTML file as a website into a single `div` element I got to hold the content. Here is my fairly simple HTML to start with. I want to put what I find in an external file on local storage into `<div class="body-content">` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My HTML5 App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/CustomStyling.css">

        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/content-controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li role="presentation" class="active" id="homeBtn">
                    <a href="#"><b>Home </b><i class="ionicons ion-ios-home"
                                               style="
                                               font-size: 22px;
                                               vertical-align: middle;"></i>
                    </a>                    
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" id="feriefribookingBtn">
                    <a href="#"><b>Ferie Fri Booking </b><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"
                                               style="
                                               font-size: 20px;
                                               vertical-align: middle;"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" id="pinfinityBtn">
                    <a href="#"><b>P - </b><i class="ionicons ion-ios-infinite" 
                                      style="
                                      font-size: 22px; 
                                      vertical-align: middle;"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" id="manpowerBtn">
                    <a href="#"><b>Manpower </b><i class="ionicons ion-ios-people"
                                               style="
                                               font-size: 24px;
                                               vertical-align: middle;"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="body-content">
            <div class="jumbotro" style="text-align: center;"><h1>Home</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="body-footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So it's basically a web app or similar, embedded into my website as it's own independant element running as if I accessed the HTML as it's own website. This is my first attempt at a single page website, so bear with me if I am asking something insane :)

I don't know how to do this currently. Please help? :)

Comment: Take a look at [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `jQuery.load` function:

```
$("#body-content").load("link_to_your_file.html");
```

See documentation for more details.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll check it out :)